# QuerySyntaxException : Hibernate not recognizing the postgres query syntax in java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I am facing problem of executing the following query in java using hibernate for postgres tables.

The query is made up to retrive the data from 3 tables using Inner Joins.

### Query :

QryJourney = "SELECT journey.id , journey.operatingday, journey.linename, journey.scheduledeparture, journey.scheduledeparturestopname, journeydetail.stopname , journeydetail.latitude, journeydetail.longitude FROM journey left join journey_journeydetail ON journey.id = journey_journeydetail.journey_id left JOIN journeydetail ON journey_journeydetail.journeydetails_id = journeydetail.id WHERE journey.id = '155815228' ORDER BY journeydetail.schedulearrival";

as soon as it executes, following exception occured.

### Exception :

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 268 [SELECT journey.id , journey.operatingday, journey.linename, journey.scheduledeparture, journey.scheduledeparturestopname, journeydetail.stopname , journeydetail.latitude, journeydetail.longitude FROM de.db.journeyTracker.model.journey left join journey_journeydetail ON journey.id = journey_journeydetail.journey_id left JOIN journeydetail ON journey_journeydetail.journeydetails_id = journeydetail.id WHERE journey.id = '155815228' ORDER BY journeydetail.schedulearrival]

Tis query works 100% fine at postgres while executing on its SQL Pane.
Anybody having any idea?

Regards
Usman

Comment: Check if the single quote causes any problem

Comment: there is no `ON` keyword in hql; hql <> sql. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Comment: HQL != SQL. SQL works on tables. HQL works on entities.

Comment: Try using a native query, see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/query_native.html

Comment: JB Nizet : so how the above problem can be resolved out, WE have build entities ( classes corresponding to tables ). Actually there are some .hbm.xml files corresponding to these entities as mappers.
So what should we use instead of standard SQL syntax like .NET LINQ

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate queries are written in  [Hibernate Query Language (HQL)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) not in native SQL. Rephrase your query in HQL or use a  [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-querying-nativesql) to use SQL with Hibernate.

Hibernate is an object-relational mapper. It won't just give you a result set. If you want that, use [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) directly, using [PgJDBC](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/).

If you want native domain objects as query results, use Hibernate with HQL or via a native query mapping. Native queries are fiddlier becuse you have to explicitly tell Hibernate how all the result columns map to your result objects.